# How do you run and compare two sorting algorithms and see which one finishes first?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Is parallel processing going to be necessary?

Comment: Run them one at a time with the same data and measure elapsed time. If you run them in parallel, there will be main memory conflicts.

Comment: The process you want to know about is called "benchmarking".

Comment: **[Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use `Stopwatch` class to run one algorithm and then run the other one.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// Code for your algorithm    

stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Make sure you test your algorithm with numerous size inputs. A sorting algorithm which performs faster than another algorithm on small set may not necessarily perform faster on a larger set.